# How can I automate cutting a video along loud beep sounds?

Tags: editing, audio, automation

I recorded videos (mp4) of participants in an experiment doing a task at a laptop. There are three tasks, at the beginning and end of which there is a loud beep sound.
I would like to automatically have cuts or extract the parts of the video between the beeps.

So far I've only been able to find this answer:
[Automatically cut out sections of a video delineated by a sound.](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/automatically-cut-out-sections-of-a-video-delineated-by-a-sound)

Can anyone help further? I am able to do a little scripting, but I wouldn't know where to start and I'm hoping that since then there's maybe been a solution with a GUI.

I have a mac, but if necessary could find a pc somewhere.

Many thanks,